# Set the ticks of facet plot with ggplotly separatly for each plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
concrete <- data.frame(x=c(-0.005,-0.004962,-0.003751,-0.002481,-0.001945,-0.001211,-0.0002481,0,0.0001316,0.001447),
                   y=c(0,-4,-4.6011,-5,-4.8555,-3.9414,-0.9901,0,0.5303,0),mat="Concrete")

UHPC <- data.frame(x=c(-0.0035,-0.002572,0,0.0001169,0.004), 
               y=c(-18.7,-18.7,0,0.85,0.85),mat="UHPC")

tendon <- data.frame(x=c(-0.036,-0.03,-0.0181,-0.011,-0.008592,0,0.008592,0.011,0.0181,0.03,0.036),
                 y=c(-251.1609,-268.2609,-266.3986,-259.9265,-244.8773,0,244.8773,259.9265,266.3986,268.2609,251.1609),
                 mat="Tendon")

material <- rbind(concrete,UHPC,tendon)
```

I want to increase the ticks in the both x and y-axis for each of the facets individually.

```
ggplot(material) +
 aes(x = x, y = y, colour=mat) + geom_line(size = 0.72) + theme_classic() +
 labs(x = "Strain (in/in)", y = "Stress (ksi)") + scale_color_hue() +
  facet_wrap(vars(mat), scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,25,0,0), size=12, colour="black"),
  axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(20,0,0,0),size=12, colour="black"),
  axis.text.y = element_text(size=11, colour="black"),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size=11, colour="black"),
  legend.position="none") + guides(colour=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. It is a bit longer what allows you to specify the breaks. You will have to define the colors and number of breaks in a different dataframe and merge them. The function is designed to sketch the plot you expect using `patchwork`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)
#Data
concrete <- data.frame(x=c(-0.005,-0.004962,-0.003751,-0.002481,-0.001945,-0.001211,-0.0002481,0,0.0001316,0.001447),
                       y=c(0,-4,-4.6011,-5,-4.8555,-3.9414,-0.9901,0,0.5303,0),mat="Concrete")
UHPC <- data.frame(x=c(-0.0035,-0.002572,0,0.0001169,0.004), 
                   y=c(-18.7,-18.7,0,0.85,0.85),mat="UHPC")
tendon <- data.frame(x=c(-0.036,-0.03,-0.0181,-0.011,-0.008592,0,0.008592,0.011,0.0181,0.03,0.036),
                     y=c(-251.1609,-268.2609,-266.3986,-259.9265,-244.8773,0,244.8773,259.9265,266.3986,268.2609,251.1609),
                     mat="Tendon")
material <- rbind(concrete,UHPC,tendon)
#Create key for breaks
mybreaks <- data.frame(mat=c('Concrete','UHPC','Tendon'),
                       xbreaks=c(3,5,6),
                       ybreaks=c(6,5,4),
                       color=c('tomato','palegreen','cyan3'))
mybreaks$Pos <- 1:nrow(mybreaks)
#Merge
df1 <- material %>% left_join(mybreaks)
#Split in a list
List <- split(df1,df1$mat)
#Function for plot
myplot <- function(x)
{
  G <- ggplot(x) +
    aes(x = x, y = y, colour=mat) + 
    geom_line(size = 0.72,color=unique(x$color)) + theme_classic() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(x$x),max(x$x),length.out = unique(x$xbreaks))) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(min(x$y),max(x$y),length.out = unique(x$ybreaks))) +
    labs(x = "Strain (in/in)", y = "Stress (ksi)") + 
    facet_wrap(vars(mat), scales = "free") +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0,25,0,0), size=12, colour="black"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(20,0,0,0),size=12, colour="black"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size=11, colour="black"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size=11, colour="black"),
          legend.position="none") + guides(colour=FALSE)
  if(unique(x$Pos)!=2){G <- G+xlab('')}
  if(unique(x$Pos)!=1){G <- G+ylab('')}
  return(G)
}
#Apply
Lplot <- lapply(List, myplot)
#Arrange
GF <- wrap_plots(Lplot,nrow = 1)
```

Output:

[image]